# Enlace a otro componente que lleva un dato no funciona

Tags: angular, formularios, routerlink

uso Angular 14, node 16, tengo un componente con un botón que tiene adentro un enlace y textbox, lo que quiero es ir a otro componente (the-search) enviándole lo que se escribió en el textbox, pero no funciona, se ve el valor del tex en la consola pero el enlace no lleva al otro componente.

menu.component.ts

```
onKeypressEvent(event: any){
    console.log(event.target.value);
    this.message = event.target.value; 
 }
```

menu.component.html

```
      <form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
            <input type="text" formControlName="video"   (keypress)="onKeypressEvent($event)" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    </form>    
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
            <a [routerLink]="['/the-search', message]">Search</a>

</button>
```

app.routing

```
{ path: 'the-search/:message', component: TheSearchComponent },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utiliza `router.navigate()` dentro de la función en lugar de usar `routerLink`

```javascript
    //La importación seria desde aquí
    
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    
    //En tu constructor inyectas la dependencia
    
    constructor(
      //...
      private router: Router  ) {}
    
    onKeypressEvent(event: any){
        console.log(event.target.value);
        this.message = event.target.value; 
        this.router.navigate(['/the-search', this.message])
     }
```